# display 'predictionEngine' in ML.net

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I'm trying to use ML.net in my project.  I want to display the predictionEngine columns value. but I don't know how to do that, 
[this picture show the predictionEngine output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx1Jo.png)

can anyone help me to display this columns??

```
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        // Training code used by ML.NET CLI and AutoML to generate the model
        ModelBuilder.CreateModel();

        //Load the saved model into your application
        ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(GetAbsolutePath(MODEL_FILEPATH), out DataViewSchema inputSchema);
        var predEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlModel);
        //Use the PredictionEngine to predict the Algorithm ModelInput label

        // Try a single prediction
        ModelOutput predictionResult = predEngine.Predict(Input);

        return predictionResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may add this to your source code

```
 Console.WriteLine("Using model to make single prediction -- Comparing actual Spam with predicted Spam from sample data...\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {sampleData.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nActual Spam: {sampleData.Spam} \nPredicted Spam: {predictionResult.Prediction}\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("=============== End of process, hit any key to finish ===============");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to the console by looping through the schema:

```
        predEngine.OutputSchema.ToList().ForEach(v =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Name);
        });
```